# Is it poosible generate asp control dynamically at the code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I want to generate asp controls(e.g check box) based on the record values for users to send request to edit database records. If not, is there any alternatives to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

We can not able to use server control dynamically use html control and call ajax jquery

refer this link

[Dynamically Create Checkboxes from AJAX Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691776/dynamically-create-checkboxes-from-ajax-response)