# Insert Check boxes in ajax success function on the basis of result of previous dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack and I am a bit stuck right now:

-> I wanted to load some check boxes from table on the basis of the previous drop down result.

Like for say I have a field called `exercise_type` which is a drop down and all the options in drop down are stored in a table and each `exercise_type` has 10 exercises related to it.

[see image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bWeK.png)

here `value` in table is `exercise_type`

and each `value` has 10 more values.

here is how I am adding this `exercise_type` field in Crudcontroller.

```
$this->crud->addField([ // select_from_array
        'name' => 'exercise1_type',
        'label' => "Exercise 1",
        'type' => 'select2',
        'entity' => 'Exercise_group',
        'attribute' => 'value',
        'model' => 'App\Models\Exercise_group',
        //'allows_null' => false,
        'attributes' => [ 
        'id' => 'exercise',
        'OnChange' => 'getexercise()',
        ]
        
        // 'allows_multiple' => true, // OPTIONAL; needs you to cast this to array in your model;
    ], 'update/create/both');
```

I am able to load the values from table till here.

And then I overrided the view of create view and added this to bring check boxes in ajax success function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getexercise(){
    var exercise = $('#exercise').val();
    alert(exercise);
    $.ajax({
    url : "../../getexercise",
    type : "POST",
    data : { id : exercise },
    success: function(response){
        
        // what to put here to bring checkboxes with the name of exercises 
           as in table
    }
    });
};
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::post('/getexercise','BlahController@getexercise');
```

And here is my BlahController.php

```
public function getexercise(Request $request){
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $exercises = Exercise_group::where('id', $id)->first();
    $exercise_id = $exercises->id;
    $exercise_1 =  $exercises->exercise1;
    $exercise_2 = $exercises->exercise2;
    $exercise_3 = $exercises->exercise3;
    $exercise_4 = $exercises->exercise4;
    $exercise_5 = $exercises->exercise5;
    $exercise_6 = $exercises->exercise6;
    $exercise_7 = $exercises->exercise7;
    $exercise_8 = $exercises->exercise8;
    $exercise_9 = $exercises->exercise9;
    $exercise_10 = $exercises->exercise10;
    
    
    return response()->json([
    'exercise_id' => $exercise_id,
    'exercise1' => $exercise_1,
    'exercise2' => $exercise_2,
    'exercise3' => $exercise_3,
    'exercise4' => $exercise_4,
    'exercise5' => $exercise_5,
    'exercise6' => $exercise_6,
    'exercise7' => $exercise_7,
    'exercise8' => $exercise_8,
    'exercise9' => $exercise_9,
    'exercise10' => $exercise_10,
    //'state' => 'CA'

]);
}
```

I am not able to add check boxes in ajax success function everything is working just fine. I have tried these links but they are not working as such:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691776/dynamically-create-checkboxes-from-ajax-response)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937720/how-can-i-append-checkboxes-to-my-ajax-response)

**EDIT::**

Now Checkboxes are working like this:

```
$.each(response, function (key, value) {

                var li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" name="' + key + '" id="' + key + '"/>' +
                           '<label for="' + key + '"></label></li>');
                li.find('label').text(value);
                
                $('#wkslist').append(li);
                console.log(value);
                $('#exercise_detail').val(value);
            });
```

but they are not being shown in a nice way so if I want to add these checkboxes values to another dropdown in backpack laravel as I am trying in example but not working:

```
$('#exercise_detail').val(value);

$this->crud->addField([   // Select2Multiple = n-n relationship (with pivot table)
        'name' => "exercise1_type_detail",
        'label' => "Exercise 1 : Detail",
        'type' => 'select2_multiple',
        'attributes' => [ 
        'id' => 'exercise_detail',
        //'OnChange' => 'getexercisedetail()',
        ],
        
    ],  'update/create/both');
```

Comment: i really didnt understand what you are trying to say .. can you make it more simple to understand or elaborate your question a little more in detail please .

Comment: @FaisalMehmoodAwan in backpack laravel I have overridden the create view and added a ajax call on success where I want to call check boxes on the basis of the type of exercise selected see the table and links. I am not able to add checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax request, add a property  *dataType: 'json'*

Assuming that, your JSON looks like below,

```
[{'exercise_id' : 'Barbel',
'exercise1' : 'Flat',
'exercise2' : 'Incline',
'exercise3' : NULL,
'exercise4' : 'Flat',
'exercise5' : NULL,
'exercise6' : 'Flat',
'exercise7' : 'Barbel',
'exercise8' : 'Flat',
'exercise9' : 'Barbel',
'exercise10' : 'Flat'}]
```

and inside the success, add the following lines of code.

```
if(response){
    var data = response[0];
    for(var i = 1; i< 10; i++){
       if(data['exercise'+i]){
        str = '<input type="checkbox" class="exercise+'i'" /> data['exercise'+i] ';
         $("#container").append(str);
       }
    }
}
```

The above sample, will work for you. do add **dataType: 'json'** in your $.ajax request.

Comment: Actually I figured a way out to bring checkboxes and it is working but if I want to add every option to backpack laravel another dropdown i am using `$('#exercise_detail').val(value);` to do so but it is not working.Check my edit